# Transforming inside CustomDataset or inside CustomDataloader - which is better? pytorch

Tags: pytorch, dataset, dataloader

Do I want to apply transformations to augment data inside the **CustomDataloader** class in Pytorch, or should I do it in the **CustomDataset** class? I would be grateful if you could show an example of how to use it correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For more flexibility, this should transformations and augmentations should be applied in the dataset, not the data loader. The latter is only there to sample and assemble the batch elements together.